# Angular *ngIf called multiple times, using async pipe and subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm facing an issue with my current angular setup and I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.
I will first describe some context before I go to the problem.

I have a class - data-service.ts, which has a method "getData" inside. This is the body:

```
getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('user_id', this.userId);
return this.http.get<Data[]>('api/data', {
  observe: 'body',
  responseType: 'json',
  params
}).pipe(
    map((response: any[]) => {
      return response.map((s) => ({
        id: s.id,
        userId: s.user_id,
        type: s.type_id,
        ...
      }));
    })
);}
```

My requirement is to fetch this data and refresh the view every time user enters a targeted tab in ngModal.
Modal component "modal-component.ts" fetches this data when you click that targeted tab. Clicking on the tab fires an event, by this piece of code:

```
getData(evt) {
  this.data$ = this.dataSevice.getData();
}
```

I'm passing this "data$" observable to child component using async pipe:

```
<modal-component>
...
    <app-data-manager [data]="data$ | async"></app-data-manager>
...
</modal-component>
```

Inside of "data-manager" I'm using *ngFor on [data], and for every data I'm rendering some html. In that HTML I'm using *ngIf to determine which template, first or second, should be rendered.

```
<div *ngIf="isTrue(dataEntry); then first else second"></div>
```

**Problem is:**
isTrue method is called for every dataEntry, which is fine, but it's getting called a multiple times for entire data set. Like hundreads of times. I tried to using promises, using Take(1) pipe, assigning boolean (the one that ngIf uses to choose template) during mapping, assigning data inside of a subscribe and passing normal collection instead of using async pipe. I don't know that is causing this - I appreciate every help on that one. Thank you!

**Additional info** When I use dataEntry.isTrue instead of isTrue(dataEntry) in *ngIf - I'm still getting same results. I also added "OnChanges" in child component with console log inside - on first click it logs to console once, on second click it logs to console twice. Two same messages appear.

Comment: This is due to change detection, you are calling a method on your template expression. `isTrue(dataEntry)` this is the issue.

Comment: @penleychan I changed it to use dataEntry.boolean instead of isTrue(dataEntry). Still the same. Also - change detection is called twice on second click on that component.

Comment: Please add the relevant codes to your updated question. What is `dataEntry` what's in your `onChange`?

Comment: In developement, change detection is run twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using a function call in an angular expression. Don't do this.

> [T]he `isTrue()` function is executed every time Angular change detection runs. And that can be many times!

> Because Angular cannot predict whether the return value of `isTrue()` has changed, it needs to execute the function every time change detection runs.

This means that any change detection throughout the app (including outside of `app-data-manager` component) will cause `isTrue()` to execute.

This article talks about it more: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

One solution is to use properties instead of a function. If you want to wrap up complex logic, opt for making a custom pipe like so.

```
*ngIf="(dataEntry | isTruePipe); then first else second"></div>
```